# adding three submit buttons inside a modal dialg box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

And my second question ,,

I have a simple modal box opening when I click on 'add users' . The modal box contains 3 submit buttons ( add, delete, and submit) . I have done this with the help of a javascript. 
 The html code is

```
<div id="overlay">
<div><a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>X</a>
<form action="" method="POST">  
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:120px;">
        user<input style="width:100px;" name="u" type="text"/> 
    </td>

    <td>        
        <input type ="submit" value = "add"> <input type="submit" value="delete"><br>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
        <select style="width:150px;">
            <option value="abc">abc</option>
        </select>
        <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/> </div></div><a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>Click here to add user</a>
```

and my javascript is

```
function overlay() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";}
```

now my task is to to add a user when user types a name in the text field and press a add button, the same user name should come in the drop down list   and similarly if user selects one name from the dropdown list and press the delete button , it should delete that name .

And finally if he press the submit button then only the modal box should close and the datas will be shown on my main page..

I have just started doing my task and am planning to implement these functionality using php and some file operations .

My first question is as user first press the add button  ,, it will close the modal window and that is not what i am required ( I guess you understand my requirement )  Is there any way to solve this?   Please help this newbie    Thank you.

Comment: You want to save action in database? Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: @DonovanCharpin Sir ,, actually i am planning to use a file for saving and deleting datas. I will take the input save it in a file , and using php variable i wanna show this in drop down  ,, I donno how much efficient is this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add eventsListeners to the button and prevent their default behave.

```
(function(){
    var addButton = document.getElementById("add_btn");
    var deleteButton = document.getElementById("delete_btn");
    addButton.addEventListener("click", addUser, false);    
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteUser, false);  
})();

function addUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var element = event.target;
    var userNameInput = document.getElementById("user_text");
    var userName = userNameInput.value;

    var usersList = document.getElementById("users_list");   
    var user = document.createElement('option');
    user.value = userName;
    user.innerHTML = userName;
    usersList.appendChild(user);
    usersList.selectedIndex = usersList.length - 1;

    userNameInput.value = "";
}

function deleteUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var usersList = document.getElementById("users_list"); 
    usersList[usersList.selectedIndex].remove();
}
```

Here an example I wrote on jsFiddle of your code:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7ttG/)

Comment: This is Superb Mr. Expert!!   one more question is that ,, can i open a file and save/write these user information there?

Comment: When you click on the submit button, by the form `action` attribute, the browser create a Request to the the action with `post` type.
Then you have to use server-side code( In your case is php I'm suggesting)
Try to google about php post
here is a http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: so may be I could write php in which it will take all the values which are there during submit, into an array and i can save it in a file in a format say csv (putcsv),   So is the var usersList contains the data? if no , where can i get it ,, ?

Comment: If you want to submit all the selected list you have to add an hidden field for holding the all users any time.
see my update http://jsfiddle.net/h7ttG/2/
then on server read the post I attached last comment for how get the information from the request on the server.
For working with files on php read this 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: is there anyway to keep the data in the dropdown box even if the page is refreshed? because even if the page is refreshed , the added users should be there ? am i right?

Comment: Yes, but you have to do it with php.
after you get the list of names from the server with `$_POST` you need to fill the selectlist with the values.
can you show what did you try to do so far (php)?

Comment: hi i think am confused.. this is my small php test                            <?
if (isset($_POST['users_hidden']) ) 
{ 
  $add=($_POST['users_hidden']);
}
?>
            <select id="users_list" style="width:150px;">
            <option value="abc"><?'.$add.'?></option>                      I added this under the delete button to see whether it is taking and i didnt change anything on the javascript,, thats why the value is coming on the dropdown still.. how can i get the variable value from js in php??  pls help

Comment: Shoul i remove user.innerHTML = userName; in js and try?  but i dont think i am right..

Comment: Yes you doing right except this you should write inside the select 'for loop' and the somthing like 'echo $add ' but you have first split the 'add' to array. Search for split function in php and after you split to array by delimiter like ',' you can iterate over any value and echo it into the select list

Comment: I am planning to do this,, am taking the js variable in a hidden input field ,, from there am reading into a php variable array and put into the dropdown list.. but am checking each value(  <?if($add[0]) { echo '<option> '.$add[0]. '</option>} if($add[1])........ etc.. but this is not efficient as the contents may be in any no (as you mentioned). how to do that easily   ?.  also can we avoid adding of blank content?

Comment: foreach will do it,,,     anyway thanx for the help,,  a +1 is definitely there for u on the day when i reach 15 reputation !!!

Comment: I'm not php programmer but you can check for blank values on the client-side(javscript) and the server. you can find anything you need on google.
the main concept is to split the value that comes from the browser of the username beacuse it's sepereate by comma.
So php has build in function to split string by char or string.
Then you have an array of the values and you just iterate it with foreach exactly like you did.
If you will upload your code it will be more easier to help you considering the fact that i'm not php expert but it's very basic so I think i can help.

Comment: upvoted as I promised ( got 15+ reputation)   thnk u

Answer (score 0):

Make your form submits using AJAX...default submit btn will refresh the page.
I assuming when you add/delete a user...you are actually saving them in the db.

1.When you press 'Add' btn...make an ajax call to the backend with the user details and save it and send a callback whether the user has been added successfully or not.
2. On the add user callback...you can call a function to update the drop-down list.

Comment: Hi ,, truely saying , I donno what this Ajax is, ? may be because i am doing my first website  .. could you pls give me some gem suggestions??

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous javascript used to communicate with the server. First of all are you using a db to store the usernames or your website is just a static website?

Comment: Actually I am using a file to save datas

Comment: As you are using php as your backend...you can write this data to a file.